# Run multiple tasks at the same time using TAP

Tags: multithreading, task, tap

My code is supposed to simultanously start sorting 3 different lists using different methods and return the first one to finish. However it always performs the first task on the list instead. How can I fix that?
Below is part of my code which seemed relevant to show.

```
static List<Task<List<int>>> listoftasks = new List<Task<List<int>>>() { QuickSortAsync(list1), BubbleSortAsync(list2), SelectionSortAsync(list3) };

    public async static void caller()
    {
        List<int> result = await Task.WhenAny(listoftasks).Result;
        foreach (var item in result)
            Console.Write(item + ", ");
    }

    static Task<List<int>> QuickSortAsync(List<int> l)
    {
        return Task.Run<List<int>>(() =>
            {
                l.Sort();
                return l;
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your list of tasks is `static`, you're starting all three tasks very early. Then, when you call `WhenAny`, it's likely that they've already all completed.

I suggest you start the tasks when you call `WhenAny`:

```
public static async Task CallerAsync()
{
  List<int> result = await await Task.WhenAny(QuickSortAsync(list1),
      BubbleSortAsync(list2), SelectionSortAsync(list3));
  foreach (var item in result)
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
}
```